# Jquery Click Function

Tags: jquery

Not sure why this is happening. When you click one my link the images from the top will slide down and if you click on one of those images they will slide back up. This works exactly how I want it to. However, when you go back and click on the link again after has already slid up, it doesnt activate the slide down on the first click. It takes two clicks. I would like it to take only one click.

http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/FzqfZ/2/

Does anyone know why this is happening? and How do I fix this and keep the sliding function the same?

Comment: to clarify: when you click on the link it expands, and if you click it again, it collapses, and this works fine. But after expanding, if you click on the image, it collapses fine, but it takes 2 clicks on the link to expands again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It hides because your if/else statement says - if item is active, then remove active and skip to end.

```
if($menuelement.hasClass('active'))
```

This code works fine if you click same menu item twice, but not if you click the images. You need to remove the active class on image click. Modify this code to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/FzqfZ/4/

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $(".thumb").hide(500);
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: This is a much better way to do this. Thanks for the help! I learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the hide function at the end of your JS to remove the active class when you hide the thumb...

```
    $(".hide").click(function(){
        $(".thumb").hide(500).removeClass('active');
    });
```